# How to protect against the IllegalAccessException?

Tags: java, reflection, field

I  research following JDK method:

```
java.lang.reflect.Field#get
```

it  throws `IllegalAccessException`    if the underlying field is inaccessible.

Am I right I can protect my code against the exception if I will add following line

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

?

Is there another ways to  get this exception?

Comment: Downvoters, please clarify why

Comment: Upvoted. I agree, downvoting without reason has become a real bad habit on Stackoverflow, particularly on the Java related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that you can protect your code that way, however, I'd suggest doing it the following way:

```
Field field = ...;
boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
field.setAccessible(true);
//Your code
field.setAccessible(accessible);
```

Using the above method is just a bit of a safety, for example, suppose your working with some API that depends on the field being accessible or not accessible, that API won't work properly if you don't set the field back to its original state.

Comment: try finally your friend)